# Reading until I manage to enter an integer

Tags: c, integer, scanf

I'm pretty new in C, I used to work in Python, and I'm trying to see if something that I read is integer number. If not, to read until I manage to entry a number.

I did some research and I found out that the function `scanf` actually returns 1 if the read is done suitably, and 0 otherwise.
So, I have written this code, and I don't understand why this is an infinite loop, writing "Give an integer" on the console

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b = 1;
    do {
        printf("Give an integer\n");
        b = scanf("%d", &a);
    } while (b == 0);
}
```

Comment: [intigers are wonderful things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJFyz73MRcg)

Comment: The problem is that `scanf()` does not consume the data that fails to match your field descriptor.  Therefore, when you loop back to try again, the same non-matching data is still waiting to be handled.

Comment: It works! But I don t really understand why:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don t understand why this is an infinite loop, writing "Give an intiger" on the console

The problem is that `scanf()` does not consume data that it cannot match against the specified format.  It leaves such characters unread in the input stream.  Therefore, if you try reading again from the same stream with the same format, without consuming at least one character by some other means, then you can be certain that the input will again not be matched.  And again.  And again.

To avoid your infinite loop, you need to consume at least one character of the non-matching input after each matching failure.  There are many ways you could do that; here's a fairly simple one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;

    do {
        printf("Give an intiger\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &a)) {
            // breaks from the loop on a successful match or an error
            break;
        }
        // consume the remainder of one line of input without storing it
        if (scanf("%*[^\n]") == EOF) {
            break;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

That consumes the whole remainder of the line on which the non-matching input is encountered, which will yield less surprising interactive behavior for some inputs than many alternatives would.

If you've a penchant for writing terse code, or if you don't like to `break` out of the middle of a loop, then you might write the same thing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;

    do {
        printf("Give an intiger\n");
    } while ((scanf("%d", &a) == 0) && (scanf("%*[^\n]") != EOF));
}
```

Because the `&&` operator short circuits, the second `scanf()` call will be executed only if the first returns zero, and the loop will exit after the first iteration wherein either the first `scanf()` call returns nonzero or the second returns `EOF` (indicating an error).

Comment: also adding getchar() after scanf works just fine. But why the function scanf does not consume data of specific formats? It s a bug or a language desing decision?

Comment: @DANIROLST, adding `getchar()` after the failed `scanf()` will avoid an *infinite* loop, but it will nevertheless produce surprising behavior for some inputs.  Try, for example, with "abc123".

Comment: @DANIROLST, the C standard clearly specifies this aspect of `scanf()`'s behavior.  And, it makes sense: if `scanf()` consumed the non-matching data then that data would be *lost*, with no mechanism for getting it back.  Moreover, if `scanf()` wanted to consume some non-matching input, then just how much do you suppose it should consume?  There's no answer that would be right for every circumstance.

Comment: @DANIROLST: There are a number of text-processing applications where you would want to leave non-matching input in place and try again with a different format, rather than discarding it.

Comment: Ohh, now it makes sense. I asked this question cuz i have never met a situation when i was supposed to use some data that was not correctly given by the user and i thought that information should just be lost.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `scanf()` is that it stops reading when the first white space is encountered for most specifiers like `"%d"`, so it's left in the input and that's why reading again would cause a problem if you don't discard such white space because it will then return immediately the next time you call it. There is a mandatory white space that is introduced when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>, the `'\n'` new line character (*or line feed*).

If you want to read an integer and make sure you did you can try like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(void)
{
    long int value; // You can adapt this to use `int'
                    // but be careful with overflow
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL) {
        char *endptr;
        value = strtol(line, &endptr, 10);
        if ((isspace(*endptr) != 0) && (endptr != line))
            break;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%ld\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

read [strtol()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)'s manual to understand this code

You could as suggested in the comments, remove the white space characters from the input, but IMHO that is harder and you would still have other problems with `scanf()`, like handing empty input which is not straight forward.

Comment: It's at best misleading to say that `scanf()` ignores whitespace characters, and to the extent that it's true of the OP's *use* of `scanf()` it does not explain the problem he describes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are absolutely right! I fixed it and I think now it's easier to understand the problem with OP's code.

Comment: `(isspace(*endptr) != 0)` allows entry of `"123 456"` as valid.  Perhaps `(*endptr = '\n' || *endptr = '\0')`?